# redirecting from short url

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirect

Let's say short.com is the short domain and long.com is the long domain

updated:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.long.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://long.com/ [R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^short\.li$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/redirect
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /redirect?short=$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)short\.li$
RewriteRule ^$ http://long.com/ [L,R=301]
```

both domains point to that root directory. When I type short.li I end up on long.com/?l=
how did I manage to screw up like that?^^

Comment: Need a bit more information on your current implementation to give an accurate answer. Your current .htaccess code would be good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this in your htaccess file :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)short\.com$
RewriteRule ^$ http://www.long.com/ [L,QSA,R=301]
```

Remove `RewriteEngine on` if it is already there

Comment: how to merge this with the redirect.php condition?    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^short\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/redirect
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /redirect?short=$1 [L]

Comment: I have no idea how to make new lines here -.-

Comment: I simply merged these 2. How the hell do I end up with: long.com/?l=  when going to short.com?

Comment: I don't understand what you write here, please edit your question with the new code

Answer (score 0):

I think you might want something along the lines of this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond {REQUEST_URI} !/
RewriteCond {HTTP_HOST} short.com
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://long.com/redirect.php?short=$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond {REQUEST_URI} /
RewriteCond {HTTP_HOST} short.com
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://long.com/ [L,R=301]
```

Not sure if the regex is needed on that last one or not, but something like this should work

Comment: Actually.. never mind. I don't think my first condition will work, because it will skip the URL code. Yazmat's answer is better.